# real time counter with livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

i am new with livewire.
I try to make a counter in real time, the counter shows the amount of products in the user's cart

```
  class Counter extends Component
{

    public $counter = '';
    
    public function render()
    {
          
     
        return view('livewire.contadorpedido');
    }


    public function counter()
    {

        $cartCollection = Cart::getContent();

        $this->counter = $cartCollection->count();
      
    }
}
```

Blade:

```
 <div>
    
    {{$counter}}
  
 
</div>
```

**method to add products:**

```
   \Cart::add([
            'id' => $product->id,
            'name' => $product->nombre,
            'price' => $product->precio,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'attributes' => array(
                'image' => $product->imagen,
            )
        ]);
```

The problem is that in the view it does not show me any value.
Adding products does not update or show the counter number either.

Comment: Can you show how you add product?

Comment: @KhangTran yess, update my post

Comment: Can you provide full code? You put in a method of a Livewire Component, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where u calling function counter()? maybe call on render method like this

```
public function render()
{
    $this->counter();
 
    return view('livewire.contadorpedido');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a item to the Cart, you need to send a event to Counter component:

In Counter, you need to listen to Counter event

```
class Counter extends Component
{

    public $counter = '';
    protected $listeners = ['counter'];


    public function counter()
    {

        $cartCollection = Cart::getContent();

        $this->counter = $cartCollection->count();
      
    }
}
```

Then:

```
  \Cart::add([
            'id' => $product->id,
            'name' => $product->nombre,
            'price' => $product->precio,
            'quantity' => 1,
            'attributes' => array(
                'image' => $product->imagen,
            )
        ]);
 $this->emitTo('counter', 'counter');
```

Reference https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events